# оптимальное время жизни jwt токенов

Tags: безопасность, auth, token

Понимаю, что не существует единого стандарта, подходящего под все случаи, но может есть хоть примерные цифры expiration time для access_token и refresh_token соотв.? по большей части интересует в контексте интернет-магазина.

Comment: для чего именно используется этот токен?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman access_token используется для получения доступа к ресурсам, для которых необходима авторизация(собственно в нем хранятся роли и т.д.) refresh_token используется для получения нового access_token

Comment: я имею в виду для каких именно операций? насколько эти операции зависят от времени?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman все операции на данный момент достаточно тривиальны(это же интернет-магазин), так что от времени они особо не зависят

Comment: Тогда у вас в принципе может быть любое время жизни для токена. Так как от этого у вас ничего не зависит.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman а можно пожалуйста хотя-бы какие-то ориентиры? понятно ведь, что, к примеру, для access_token время жизни в год - это полный абсурд

Comment: Ничего абсурдного нет. Если у вас ничего не зависит от времени, то он может быть и год.Вот если бы вы продавали подписку ограниченную по  времени, то да надо было бы делать время жизни таким, что бы потери для вашего бизнеса были приемлемыми.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman благодарю, кажется прояснил для себя некоторые вещи:)

Comment: если будет не сложно - оформите это ответом на ваш вопрос и примите его.